# In plugin 'com.moowork.node' type 'com.moowork.gradle.node.npm.NpmSetupTask' setter 'setArgs()' should not be annotated with: @Internal

Tags: node.js, build.gradle

- In plugin 'com.moowork.node' type 'com.moowork.gradle.node.npm.NpmSetupTask' setter 'setArgs()' should not be annotated with: @Internal.

  Reason: Input/Output annotations are ignored if they are placed on something else than a getter.

  Possible solutions:

  1. Remove the annotations.
  2. Rename the method.

I am extreemly new as a dev, so maybe this is just me being stupid, but how do I do this?

I already tried searching online for a sol'n, but could not find it. If this has been asked before, and I just don't know, please give me the link to the solution.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem. According to this [article](https://dzone.com/articles/integrating-java-and-npm-builds-using-gradle), the plugin is no longer under active development and a [new fork of the project](https://github.com/node-gradle/gradle-node-plugin) has arised. Using the new plugin i was able to resolve the error.